# RecyclerView taking too long to populate a large number of Videos from User Storage

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

So I'm using Glide to load video thumbnails, but it takes a while to load a large number of videos to view, whats the best/fastest way to load a list of videos in users phone with each respective video thumbnail, in Recycler view.

Populating the list

```
    public static ArrayList<String> getAllMedia(Context context) {
    HashSet<String> videoItemHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA ,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            videoItemHashSet.add((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<String> downloadedList = new ArrayList<>(videoItemHashSet);
    return downloadedList;
}
```

The Glide Method

```
    public static void displayImageOriginal(Context ctx, ImageView img, String url) {
    try {
        Glide.with(ctx).load(url)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform().skipMemoryCache(false).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                .into(img);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Here's the adapter view Binder

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final YVideos obj = items.get(position);
    if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
        OriginalViewHolder view = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;

        view.video_title.setText(obj.title);
        view.duration_size.setText(obj.getDurSize());
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(ctx, view.video_thumbnail, obj.name);
    } else {
        SectionViewHolder view = (SectionViewHolder) holder;
        view.title_section.setText(obj.title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see your current code so that we can make suggestions? Generally speaking, the `RecyclerView` should handle these kinds of efficiency problems, and you should not have to find yourself loading a "large number" of videos because the content you load should be scoped to what is visible on the screen.

Comment: @Cawfree I have edited the question with the source code

Comment: you can probably create video thumbnails (downsize them also )  and save them in file system or cache to show in recycler view, when user taps on a particular video just play using glid. This way it would be way faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all looks like standard `RecyclerView` usage, so provided your adapter is assigned to the `RecyclerView` in isolation, i.e. without definining any properties that limit performance, such as `setItemViewCacheSize()`, `setMaxRecycledViews()` and the likes, your issue is unlikely to be a client-side one.

Are you relying on `Glide` to generate the thumbnails for you, at runtime? If so, you'll be really putting the library through its paces with a lot of processing, since it has to work through the original quality, original resolution video on the fly. Would it not be possible to generate the thumbnails beforehand? These will load much faster and unburden your app from a lot of computation. If the thumbnails are going to stay the same forever, then why not compute them once and let every user benefit, rather than have every user compute the same result every time you wish to render?

It's likely to me that your issue comes from the fact that you're expecting to fetch the images and render them to the user whilst they're already looking at the content. This means that you load up the screen, and `onBindViewHolder()` is called, and you make an attempt to fetch the images from a network; but at this stage, the  user is already looking at the list and ready to browse. In a way, you're a little too late, and your `List` will only be as fast as your network connection/image server.

What you can do is prepare the image cache before you ever try to draw the `RecyclerView`. You know before you reach that screen what range of images you wish to render; it would be possible to `load` these into `Glide` and define an appropriate `diskStrategy` before you're even ready to draw. This way, you can initialize the `List` of content the moment the user is looking. The predictive image caching strategy wouldn't end here; you know what rows of images you're ready to load next; so you can fetch those in the background too. The drawback with this approach is that it has the potential to waste a lot of bandwidth fetching images your user may never even scroll down to; therefore you may need to experiment with request rate limits.

There are also sneakier ways to go about solving this problem. Even the most well funded, well researched applications depend on simple tricks to work around the bottleneck of network performance... Have you considered using a [placeholder animation](https://www.lottiefiles.com/u/27) to keep your app looking active? You'll be surprised how well these work!